# Evaluating $\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+2x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, error-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following indefinite integral:

$$
\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+2x^2)^2}dx
$$

According to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28exp%28-x%5E2%29/%28%281%2b2x%5E2%29%5E2%29%29dx), this integral evaluates to:

$$
\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+2 x^2)^2} dx = \frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{erf}(x)+\frac{2x e^{-x^2}}{(2 x^2+1)}\right)+\mathrm{constant}
$$

Is there a quick way of evaluating this integral to get that answer?  A fairly obvious-looking integration-by-parts approach didn't work but looked fairly promising:

\begin{align}
\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+2 x^2)^2} dx &= \frac{1}{4}\int \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}\times\frac{4x}{(1+2 x^2)^2}dx \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{-e^{-x^2}}{x(1+2x^2)}+\int\frac{1}{(1+2x^2)}\times\frac{-2x^2e^{-x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x(1+2x^2)}-\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}dx\right)
\end{align}

If both the boundary term and the integrand were multiplied by $-2x^2$, this would be exactly what we want, since the integral on the right would then evaluate to $\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{erf}(x)$.  Is there some other integration by parts that I've missed?  Or is it only possible to do the integral by more complicated means?

Comment: if the regular methods don't work then my next port of call would be differentiating under the integral or contour integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing integration by parts on this term as well with $u = \exp(-x^2)$ and $dv = \frac{1}{x^2}dx$. Combine some terms and I think you'll have your result.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I edited my answer because while you dropped a negative in your LaTeX code, the second term should be negative in the last equality.

Comment: Yes - thanks.  I'll change the incorrect $-$ sign now.  Also, this method did indeed work!